# Display ASCII character on LCD screen using SSD1305 with PIC24F

Tags: pic, spi, lcd

I am using a PIC24F to control an LCD screen with an SSD1305 controller via SPI protocol.

Here is my code to power up the screen according to datasheet :

```
//OLED INIT
LATFbits.LATF0 = 1; //ENV_VDD_DISPL
delay(10);
LATFbits.LATF5 = 0; //RESET
delay(1);
LATFbits.LATF5 = 1; //RESET
delay(1);
LATFbits.LATF1 = 1;
delay(1);
LATDbits.LATD7 = 0; // D/C_DISPL : Command
writeSPI2(0xAF);//Display ON
```

The power up works fine but I have a "snow screen" and but I am still confused about how to send the data to the GDDRAM.

The Microchip library for LCD controller don't seems to support SPI mode.

My question is, where can I find help ? How can I send data (ASCII or image) to the controller ? What library do you recommend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the the release notes of the [Microchip Graphics Library](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2680&dDocName=en543091) (gfx_release_notes.h) is "Added driver for Solomon Systech 132x64 OLED/PLED Display Controller SSD1305" so the gfx app should be a good place to start looking.

Also, there is source for a module specifically for the SSD1305 online [here](https://code.google.com/p/cpassgen/source/browse/repo/PIC32MTest.X/src/graphics/Drivers/SSD1305.c). Looks like you'll need to implement DeviceWrite() for SPI.